# Are the tags next to job offers randomized or, at least, automated?

Tags: discussion, tags, stack-overflow-jobs

Sometimes I peek at the job section of SO to get a feeling of what's hot and what's not. I understand the less-than-scientific methodology behind it but it still gets me an idea, not to mention the opportunity to learn new buzz words etc.

I've been under the impression that the companies' representatives picked the tags in the adds themselves but today I stumbled across [the one shown below](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/133299/net-developer-seidor). I'm rather familiar with .NET world and there's nothing that I even vaguely could refer to in terms of job offer with the tag *.net-framework-version*.

[image]

In fact even the wildest association would be by far better expressed using other tags. In that, I've taken into account that the person picking the tags might be less technically savvy.

If they target a set of specific frameworks, it's far more natural to list those. If they intend to say *wide, but unspecified, range of versions*, it's definitely more intuitive to just say *.net*.

Are the tags automatically picked? Or is there a good explanation that I simply am too limited to figure out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The job listings are tagged by the employers. While some of them may be vetted by our staff, by and large they are not. And some times you get weird tags like this.

While there *is* some algorithmic special sauce we use for matching your question view history to job tags (which is why you got the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) *tag-themed* job ad and why [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) is highlighted), the other tags in a job listing are pretty much "anything goes".

Feel free to click the "Flag a problem" link on the job listing page and one of our support staff should take a look (and possibly contact the employer to fix the tag).

Comment: I just hope it isn't a first wave of the recruiting firms trying to push in everywhere, hence corrupting a coherent and working setup.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the case. Our reps are pretty damn good about clamping down on shady practices. And I'm almost positive we don't even _allow_ recruiting firms to post job listings. We require that the company posting the job is the same company that has the job opening (**NOTE:** This is no longer true, see below)

Comment: Really? I wasn't aware that recruiters were off-limits. In that case, I have some bad news for you. I've seen quite a lot of ads where I know for a fact that the end customer is someone else (Stockholm isn't a big place and I happen to know quite many position being in the loop). Can only speak for Sweden, of course, but it seems natural that it doesn't differ.

Comment: Just to be clear - the ads I'm referring to are not written as it's a recruitment company but the actual employer. However, I've seen many times names of companies that only do a quick (totally idiotic) interview and shove ones CV to the actual employer.

Comment: It looks like I was wrong: we _do_ allow recruiters, but we require the Company Name to be filled out. We don't allow blind listings; a candidate must _always_ know the actual company they are applying to. From [here](http://talent.stackoverflow.com/house-rules)

Comment: I see. Let me keep an eye on those ads and notify you if I'll find any obvious fakes. Regrettably, I'm rather convinced that I will. Around here, many recruiter start-ups do that. They claim that the job is with them but once you pass the "filter" (which around here is equivalent to being non-idiot and interested in programming with a few years of experience), suddenly the original "opportunity" is filled by "someone else" but they feel so sorry for your ass so they can send your CV to another company. (Amazingly, often the very same requirement stack there...)